# Palatino font and renewcommand title

Tags: fonts, titles

I have tried to make a document with the font called "Palatino" and with a renew defintion of the title. Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo} %font palantino
%language
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Titlesection
\renewcommand{\title}{{\scshape \bfseries {\fontsize{50}{50}}}}

\begin{document}
\title{Hinter eines Baumes Rinde wohnt die Made mit dem Kinde. Sie ist Witwe, denn der Gatte, den sie hatte, fiel vom Blatte. Diente so auf diese Weise einer Ameise als Speise.}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

**Questions and Trouble**

My first question is: is the whole document know with the font Palatino? And my real struggle is, that the title don't do what I wanted it to do. And I am sure this is pretty basic and easy to solve, but I don't know how?

Thank you ver much in advance! Kind regards!

Comment: For things like this, KOMA-Script classes are much more easily to tweak (`scrartcl` for instance). But for this particular case, *sigh*, the size of the title font is fixed :(

Comment: @Henriette I am interested. Is this a real title you want to typeset, or just one single quote for ... let's say a flyer, or a wedding card or something like this?

Comment: @Johannes_B No it isn't the real title ;-) ... but I will make a template for my next hand in. And I had a little trouble with the title layout. Therfor I asked here. But the text in the title was just taken from a poem. So the text is just so I can see how it looks like :-)

Comment: Figured that this is not the real text ;-). I hope it is not the real font size either. Btw: If you want to know more: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993) and https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no boldface small caps font available, so you won't get it. Also `\fontsize{50}{50}` is not really something one wants to do.

What you have to modify is not the `\title` command, but the `\maketitle` command. What `\title` does is just storing the title is a safe place for later retrieval, when the document header will be typeset.

Don't forget the `sc` option to `mathpazo` to have a “real” small caps font (thanks to Manuel for noticing).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} %font Palatino
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\@title}
  {\fontsize{40}{48}\scshape\@title}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\title{Hinter eines Baumes Rinde wohnt die Made mit dem Kinde}

\author{Heinz Erhardt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ou could add the `[sc]` option to `mathpazo`.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 4):

The `titling` package allows you to reformat the title etc. relatively painlessly. However, even using egreg's font size suggestion, your title took the entire first page when I tested, without even room for the date. So I've used a somewhat smaller size for purposes of demonstration. I'd still recommend a smaller size but you may have different ideas.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,german]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\fontsize{30}{36}\scshape}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}

\begin{document}
\title{Hinter eines Baumes Rinde wohnt die Made mit dem Kinde. Sie ist Witwe, denn der Gatte, den sie hatte, fiel vom Blatte. Diente so auf diese Weise einer Ameise als Speise.}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: large title]

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{\fontsize{40}{45}\scshape\bfseries\noindent
  Hinter eines Baumes Rinde wohnt die Made mit dem Kinde. Sie ist
  Witwe, denn der Gatte, den sie hatte, fiel vom Blatte. Diente so auf diese
  Weise einer Ameise als Speise.\endgraf}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result Palatino]

A variant with the Palatino clon from the TeX Gyre project (with `\usepackage{tgpagella}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{\fontsize{40}{45}\scshape\bfseries\noindent
  Hinter eines Baumes Rinde wohnt die Made mit dem Kinde. Sie ist
  Witwe, denn der Gatte, den sie hatte, fiel vom Blatte. Diente so auf diese
  Weise einer Ameise als Speise.\endgraf}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result TG Pagella]

**Remarks:**

- `\fontsize{50}{50}` is much too large for "normal" titles. Also the `\baselineskip` (the second argument) is too small. The example uses `\fontsize{40}{45}`, still way too large.
- `\fontsize` needs `\selectfont`, which is implicitly done by `\scshape` or `\bfseries`.
- German text contains umlauts, `OT1` should *not* be used. The example uses `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.
- The `\baselineskip` is used at the end of the paragraph, therefore the paragraph should be ended, when `\fontsize` is still active. Therefore `\endgraf` is added. `\endgraf` is the harmless version of `\par` and can be used in non-`\long` arguments, where `\par` would cause an error.
- The cleaner way is to redefine `\maketitle` to add the formatting there.
  `\title` is intended for the title string only, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252837/16967) of egreg.

Comment: I beg to disagree. `;-)`